# ng-repeat not repeating specific element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-template

I'm using Angularjs to repeat some elements in my HTML. Angular repeats the divs correctly, but when trying to repeat an specific div it just doesn't work. Explanation after the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in controlList" class="tr-shadow">
   <td>{{x.fecha_control}} </td>
   <td>{{x.hora}}</td>
   <td class="desc">{{x.valor}}</td>
   <td><span class="block-background level-color--{{x.color}} ">{{x.texto}} </span></td>
   <td>
      <span class="status">{{x.momento}} </span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="table-data-feature">
         <button ng-click="editControl($event)" id="{{x.id}}" class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
         <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
         </button>
         <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
         <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
         </button>
      </div>
   </td>
<tr class="spacer"></tr>
</tr>
```

Angular repeats everything inside `<tr ng-repeat="x in controlList" class="tr-shadow"> </tr>` **BUT the last div** `<tr class="spacer"></tr>`

If I comment the *spacer* the ng-repeat it does repeat the *spacer*, but if I don't the spacer only shows once at the end of the repeated code.

```
<!--  <tr class="spacer"></tr> -->
```

I tried changing the HTML Tag for *spacer* but I'm having the same issue.
As you can see in the Chrome's debugger, the spacer shows after the repeated code:

[image: Debugger]

Comment: your html code is invalid you cannot have `tr` tag inside a `tr` tag

Comment: You must have meant `<td>`

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha then why am I having the same issue when changing the HTML tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to include your spacer in your iteration there is another option called `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`

Something like the following should work

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in controlList" class="tr-shadow">
   <td>{{x.fecha_control}} </td>
   <td>{{x.hora}}</td>
   <td class="desc">{{x.valor}}</td>
   <td><span class="block-background level-color--{{x.color}} ">{{x.texto}} </span></td>
   <td>
      <span class="status">{{x.momento}} </span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <div class="table-data-feature">
         <button ng-click="editControl($event)" id="{{x.id}}" class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
         <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
         </button>
         <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
         <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
         </button>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="spacer" ng-repeat-end>...</tr>
```

> You can find this exact information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points) on their documentation page.

Comment: This worked for me. The tr needed to be outside the ng-repeat, but even changing the tag inside the ng-repeat didn't work. Than you!

Answer (score 2):

`<tr>` inside `<tr>` is not valid html. You must include `ng-class="{'spacer': someCondition}"`

`<tr ng-repeat="x in controlList" class="tr-shadow" ng-class="{'spacer': someCondition}>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add condition ng-if="$last" to your spacer